# ExecutorService java possible thread leak

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

I'm trying to run this simple class and for each cicle, I'm counting the number of java process threads.

**ps huH p *pid* | wc -l**.

I'm testion on **centOS 6.5** with oracle **java version 1.8.0_20**.

For each cicle the **number of threads is increasing** of the number of **availableProcessors()**.

It seems that garbace collector doesn't deallocate zombie threads when ExecutorService is running inside an other thread.

If I create a static ExecutorService it does not happend

private static final ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors());).

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class ExecutorTest implements Runnable{

private ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors());
private static final int CICLE_NUMBERS=100;
private static final int WAIT_SECONDS=20;

@Override
public void run() {
    try{
    ArrayList<Future<DummyThread>> responses = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i=0;i<CICLE_NUMBERS;i++)
        responses.add((Future<DummyThread>) executor.submit(new DummyThread()));
    for (Future<DummyThread> future : responses)
        future.get(WAIT_SECONDS, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.gc();
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    for(;;){
        new Thread(new ExecutorTest()).start();
        Thread.sleep(2000);
    }
}
}

class DummyThread implements Runnable{

@Override
public void run() {
    System.out.println("Hello World!");
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

add a try/finally block inside your run() method and call `shutdownNow()` on the `executor` in the finally block.

Comment: Thanks! this solve the problem, but theoretically speaking this would be run by garbage collector? isn't it?

Comment: @user1535271 No, the GC does not collect live threads.  If you do not shut down the ExecutorService the threads will not be destroyed and the threads stay alive.  This isn't true if the threads are `daemon` in some regards.  By default the ES threads are non-daemon.

Comment: Threads are actually what _define_ live objects in java, so, by definition, the GC _cannot_ collect threads...

Comment: @JohnVint - making the threads daemon won't solve the problem of the threads living forever, it will just cause them not to block shutdown.

Comment: I was thinking like a chain:

Comment: ExecutorTest --> will be destroy by gc --> it contains ExecutorService and so I was thinking gc destory ExecutorSerivce' Threads too

Comment: Personally I think it could be done be gc, more safe

Comment: @jtahlborn you're right.  I probably shouldn't have included daemons in my comment.

Comment: @jtahlborn The GC can and does collect `Threads`.  A `Thread` is not a thread.  A thread (little 't') is an execution of your code.  A `Thread` is a Java object with methods you can call to manage the life-cycle of a thread.  It's the call stacks of the (little 't') threads that define liveness for the GC.  Every little-t thread stack contains a reference to the big T `Thread` object that manages it.  When the little-t thread dies, and its stack is gone, then the big T `Thread` can be reclaimed if there are no other references to it in the program.

Comment: @jameslarge - while your comment is technically correct, i don't think it's a necessary distinction for the purposes of this problem.

Comment: @jtahlborn, It _is_ a necessary distinction.  What is not necessary, for those of us who know the difference, is to talk about it:  When I say "thread" you don't even have to think about whether I mean `Thread` or thread, you just know.  But the noobs don't know, and our not talking about it is an obstacle that stands in the way of their learning how the language and its libraries really work.

Answer (score 0):

If you go through the code properly the reason that you are getting multiple pool objects is because of the statement

```
new Thread(new ExecutorTest()).start();
```

Every execution in the for loop is going to create a new instance of 
ExecutorService  since it is a member variable of class ExecutorTest.
Your program will keep running even without shutdown and since the
threads will not be GCed since they are alive and working till the
pools are shutdown.

If you make this a static variable then there is only one ExecutorService
object within class level and that is why you do not get multiple 
pool objects created so you better not shutdown the pool else
you will get an exception.